# Why is Scalatra warning me about log4j

Tags: scala, logging, log4j, logback, scalatra

I am attempting to get some type of logging working in Scalatra. I simply followed the instructions here http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/monitoring/logging.html. When I run `container:start` after launching with `sbt`, I see the following in my console, multiple messages that don't exactly look right:

From what I can tell, I'm attempting to use `logback`, but something is loading `log4j` later on. That's not the behavior I'm expecting, but it is what I'm seeing.

From multiple bindings to log4j warnings (I didn't add log4j anywhere in this app):

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/foo/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/foo/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.0.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
[info] started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/v1,[file:/Volumes/Macintosh%20HD%202/Dropbox/Projects/scalatra-test/src/main/webapp/]}
[info] started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/v1,[file:/Volumes/Macintosh%20HD%202/Dropbox/Projects/scalatra-test/src/main/webapp/]}
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Not entirely sure what the problem is here. I just want to be able to:

- Log some debug statements to STDOUT (assuming it would go to the term I started sbt from)
- Log some debug statements to a file that I can simply tail

My dependencies look like the following in build.scala:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.6" % "runtime",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")),
    "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.1",
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % "2.2.1",
    "org.json4s"   %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.4",
    //"org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.4",
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-swagger"  % "2.2.1",
    "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.8"
  ),
```

Is it possible something here is also requiring log4j and that's overriding logback?

Is it also possible to instruct sbt to completely exclude log4j from this project? I can't locate what's requiring it as a dependency, but it should be using logback instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin to detect what depends
   on log4j.
2. And exclude it from your build. For example:

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.2.1" exclude("org.slf4j", "log4j12")
   ```

   or

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.2.1" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))
   ```

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the answer, it should be excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j")). At least this one works for me

Comment: Original idea was to exclude log4j-slf4j bridge or all transitive slf4j dependencies and define your own. But in some cases log4j exclusion may be enough.

Comment: I ran into the same problem recently after integrating scalatra-swagger. Since my app used logback the multiple bindings issue manifested itself. Adding the following line:
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-wagger" % "2.2.2" exclude("org.slf4j", "log4j12")
removed the issue. thanks for the tip, it saved me hours of pain.